# php PDO prepare() on a non-object error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I keep getting "Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in /var/www/html/portal_core/build_portal.php on line 30".
I am new to PDO and I'm really using this as a test to get my head around it. could you guys help me to understand what I am doing wrong ?

```
 <?php

class build_portal 
{
protected $dbh; 

function __construct($dbname,$theme)
{
    try
    {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:dbname='.$dbname.';host=localhost',"username","password");
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $this->log_error("Construct 1st Try statement 3rd Line");
    }
    catch (PDOException $e)
    {
        echo "Page Could Not Be Loaded";
        return -1;
    }



}

function log_error($cause)
{
    try
    {
    $sth = $this->dbh->prepare("SELECT * from portal_errors");
    $sth->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $sth->execute();
    }
    catch (PDOException $e)
    {
        print_r($e->errorInfo);
    }
}
```

}
?>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to be a matter of scope.  You ought to assign `dbh` to `$this->dbh` in the constructor.  When you access it later in `log_error()`, you are expecting it to be a class property but it was originally defined as a local variable in the constructor.

```
$this->dbh = new PDO('mysql:dbname='.$dbname.';host=localhost',"username","password");
$this->dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Comment: Oh God damn it, soon as I started reading it I knew what I'd done thanks mate. Its always the small little stuff that catches you out!